# How do I input phi(t) approaches 1 in latex?

Tags: math-mode, errors

How do I input *φ(t)* approaches 1 in LaTeX? I have tried `$\phi(t)\to\1$` but I keep getting an error message.

Comment: what kind of error message?

Comment: the problem is `\1`. you should have `$\phi(t) \to 1$`. for readability it's better to put some more spaces in your TeX code.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in [corporal's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307226/how-do-i-input-phit-approaches-1-in-latex#comment745483_307226), your problem is that you have `\1`, when you obviously want just `1`. That is:

```
$\phi(t) \to 1$
```

[image]

To expand upon this a little, when you compiled your document you should have received the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 $\phi(t)\to\1
                  $
```

Here, you are being told what the problem is. You have an undefined control sequence, which means that one of the commands you have given is unknown to LaTeX, it doesn't know what it means!

This can mean that you have attempted to use a valid command which is actually provided by a package that you have forgotten to load. For example, `\mathbb{...}` is provided by the `amssymb` or `amsfonts` package. If you do not have `\usepackage{amssymb}` or `\usepackage{amsfonts}` you will get the undefined control sequence error if you try to use `\mathbb{...}`. The reason is that, even though the command is valid, LaTeX doesn't know it. It is defined in a package which is not loaded by default. You must load this package so that LaTeX can learn the definition of the command. Then you can use it.

However, rather often, this error is caused by a typo. In this case, you have `\1`, which I'm almost certain is a typo for `1`. LaTeX doesn't know the command `\1`, so it chokes, because it doesn't know what to do. It's like me asking you to dist your bedroom. You're gonna think, what's disting, how do I dist? Of course, I actually intended to ask you to dust your room.

So that's the problem, one of your commands is undefined and LaTeX doesn't know what to do. But the message has told you more than that. It's also told you which one. Do you see that there is `l.11`. This tells you which line of your input file the error is on. In my case it was on line 11, although in your file, the error might be on a different line.

It goes even further and tells you exactly which command is undefined. Do you see that the line is broken at `\1`. This tells you that the LaTeX got as far as `\1` before it stopped. Sometimes the error is actually not at the point LaTeX stops but actually occurs before. However, here (and in the case of most simple errors) the problem is where the line is broken.

So your message tells you that `\1` on line 11 is undefined.

You must replace it with `1`.